# places of verbs in 'entweder ... oder'

Tags: word-order

I saw a sentence like:

> Entweder besucht er später die Hochschule oder er arbeitet in einer Fabrik.

The question is the places of the verbs.

Can it be changed into

> Entweder er besucht später die Hochschule oder er arbeitet in einer Fabrik.

or

> Entweder besucht er später die Hochschule oder arbeitet er in einer Fabrik.

Comment: The first variant is most common. The third is wrong because after conjunctions word order is reset, and the finite verb is expected in second position, not in first. BUT, caveat, the second is also okay because the *Entweder* can be thought absent and this is called "zero position". It's not too common, though.

Answer (score 2):

The first version is right because the word order in the second version (second part) is the one of a question. So the listener would hear it as question "oder arbeitet er in einer Fabrik?" but without question tag.